# WP_User_Query combining role and ids

Tags: users

I would like to get array of all authors (except few), add several admins to it (by ids) and order the array by user names. But I can't find the way how to make it in one WP_User_Query.

When I called those two subqueries separately and put the results together by array_merge(), it was ok, but I need to order them by name, which was not possible in that way...

So right now I am trying something like this, but it gets me all the users. What I am doing wrong?

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'  => 'display_name',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'role' =>   'author',
            'exclude' => array(36, 41)
        ),
        array(
            'include' => array(23, 45),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: WP_User_Query does not support the nested sub-arrays you've got going on there - that sort of structure only works for the `meta_query` argument. `role`, `include`, and `exclude` are all arguments that need to be in the same top-level array as your ordering parameters, which also means you will not be able to combine them in a manner which will select the set of users you would like with a single query

Answer (score 1):

As I was told above in the comment, WP_User_Query does not support the nested sub-arrays... So at the end I solved the thing by separated queries...

Not sure whether there is more efficient way, but in case somebody needs an inspiration, below is my solution of the problem.

```
// get ids of first set of users
$authors_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'fields' => 'id',
        'role' =>   'author',
        'exclude' => array(36, 41)
    )
);
$authors = $authors_query->get_results();

// get ids of second set of users
$admins_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array (
        'fields' => 'id',
        'include' => array(23, 45),
    )
);
$admins = $admins_query->get_results();

// merge ids
$user_ids = array_merge( $admins, $authors );

// get final selection
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(
    array(
        'include'  => $user_ids,
        'orderby'  => 'display_name',
        'order'    => 'ASC',
    )
);
```